# What would be the best practices to test this Fragment?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin

Lets suppose I have a fragment class like this one below named EmailSearchResultPageFragment().

```
class EmailSearchResultPageFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_email_search_result_page, container, false)
        someFunctionThatRequiresViewFromOnCreate(view)
        showPage(fragment)
        return view
    }

    fun someFunctionThatRequiresViewFromOnCreate(view: View) {
        view.DoSomethingWithView(view)
    }
     fun showPage(fragment: Fragment) {
     fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit()

    }
}
```

If i want to unit test `someFunctionThatRequiresViewFromOnCreate(:)`, and `showPage(:)` what would be the best practice ??

How can I possibly mock `view` and `fragment` that is being instantiated inside onCreate???!

Comment: UI code is tested using [instrumented unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests).

Comment: @Sandi can't I write unit test for this? Something where I can instantiate var sut = EmailSearchResultPageFragment(), and do sut.someFunctionThatRequiresViewFromOnCreate(view)??

Comment: Well, you can refactor your logic to not use the view and into a standalone unit, otherwise you're pretty much stuck with instrumentation tests because you're interacting with the UI. You might want to look into [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org) to run Android code as a standalone unit test.

Comment: @Sandi Do you have more specific advice as to solving this problem? I am aware of Robolectric testing framework as much as I am aware of Espresso and Mockito and so forth.